# Castalia S-MAC parameters

Tags: omnet++

1. I need to have the values of some of the s-mac protocol parameters that used in Castalia. As DIFS duration, Contention Window size, size of SlotTime, backoff time, SYNC duration (duration of a sync cycle = 6 ms?) I would be very grateful if anyone gave me these values.
2. Is the CBR value obtained through `Application.packet_rate *Application.constantDataPayload` ?
3. What is the unit of Consumed Energy in the ResourceManager module? mW of nJ or ...?
4. Is `SN.numNodes` number of nodes in a virtual cluster? If not, what calculate number of nodes in a virtual cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Almost all of your questions are answered in the manual and the source code comments already. It would be good to provide some evidence that you actually tried to find the answers on your own (looking at the obvious places) and explaining why you were uncertain of the answers, or why you where unable to find the answers.

1. Most of these parameters are covered in section 4.3.2 of the manual. To understand some of them you might need to read the relevant published [article](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.671.7826&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
2. If CBR means Constant Bit Rate, then you need to multiply by 8, since `constantDataPayload` is expressed in bytes. (found in the code at iApplication.ned)
3. Units of energy are in Joules  (found in the manual, and the source code)
4. `SN.numNodes` is the total number of nodes in your simulation (found in the manual)